# how can i stop a function in a service?

Tags: android, service

I have a function::

```
public void doSleep() {
    handler.postDelayed(
        new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { doCom(); } 
        }, 10000); 
}
```

This is linked with doCom which starts this again. how can I finsh this at the end of the service?

Comment: why you want to sleep docom() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a boolean flag in your class called sleep = true;

```
public void doSleep() {
    handler.postDelayed(
        new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { if(sleep) { doCom(); } } 
        }, 10000); 
}
```

and set sleep = false; if you want to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable r);
```

Answer (score 0):

use StopService() or StopSelf() methods where you want to stop